# What exactly is a whip?

Tags: whipping

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip_(politics)) that they ensure that members of the party vote according to the party platform, rather than according to their own individual ideology or the will of their donors or constituents.

This is an unsourced claim so I am wondering if this is correct? I would have thought that is undemocratic as they should vote based on the wishes of their constituents.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_QLzthSkfM

Comment: It sounds like there is no confusion regarding what a "whip" is and that you just disagree with the existence of such a role.

Comment: `+1` and I can not understand all the down votes. Related: [Are voters in the US generally aware of how and when their congressional representatives are being whipped?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/66156/16047) where all I had to go on was Wikipedia. *I'm certain* there are useful and cite-able definitions out there (notice I didn't include "authoritative") let's hope that some can be found.

Comment: [US Senate: Party Whips](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/briefing/Party_Whips.htm) — [What does a whip actually do](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2010/03/what-does-a-congressional-whip-actually-do.html)

Comment: That was from 30 seconds of bumbling on Google. Two minutes and I could cough up a dozen. Don't trust what Wikipedia says on any political issue, ever.

Comment: No MP is forced to pay any attention whatever to his Whip. But Whips have considerable influence. For example on the Government side, a large number of MPs are needed to fill ministerial positions. These are paid offices under the Crown and such pay is in addition to the MP's salary. So when the Government is looking for people to promote it will take advice from the Whips' office on members' loyalty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on the nation in question. Generally, two issues collide:

- Representatives tend to be **free in the exercise of their mandate.**
  There may be an option of a recall vote, but unless that happens, an individual representative is elected for the term, and free to vote against previous promises and the party platform. (Besides, the platform might not even cover a novel problem.) Reckoning comes with the next election.
- Parties need to operate and **negotiate in a coherent manner.**
  When parts of the legislative meet in working [subcommittes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_committee) to hammer out a compromise, the specialists from each party (on education, defense, environment, the overall budget, ...) must be able to deliver what they promise. It wouldn't be possible to negotiate a compromise like *'we get protection in* this *wetland, you get logging in* that *forest'* if both are separate votes and there is no party line.

When the freedom of the mandate is constitutionally protected, the party leadership has to be very *polite* about communicating their wishes. This leads to fictions like the [number of times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip_(politics)#United_Kingdom) a wish is underlined in a letter. The threat/leverage of the party in this communication is party support during the next election. The legislator may be free to disregard the party, but the party is equally free *not* to support the legislator during the next election, or even not to make her or him a candidate on the party ticket.

Comment: 'the party leadership has to be very polite about communicating their wishes'  Note that OP is located in the UK, where the last few days have seen high-profile allegations of whips committing both breaches of the Ministerial Code and criminal offences in the course of trying to get certain votes to go their way.

Comment: @DanielHatton, I called the mere underlining of wishes a *fiction*. Politically speaking, I support the existence of whips, but one should be overt about it -- failure to follow the party platform in important issues leads to party expulsion, unless one manages to challenge the party leadership in the process.

Comment: @o.m.: To some extent, it also depends on whether you prefer the British system (the party chooses the candidate by internal processes) or the American system (the electorate chooses the candidate by voting in a primary). The latter is arguably more democratic but may make party discipline a harder problem to solve (some would say it puts too much power in the hands of a small number of moderates).

Answer (score 2):

[Whips](https://www.parliament.uk/about/mps-and-lords/principal/whips/) are members of a parliament who organise their party's contribution to the parliament

There is a reasonable assumption made by voters that their elected representatives will vote according to the party platform on which they were elected, and more generally in a manner consistent with the ideals and philosophy of that party.

That is to say, if a constituency elects a Conservative candidate as MP, it is a reasonable expectation that the MP should vote as a Conservative.  And it is the whips' job to ensure that the constituents' expectations are met.

Comment: Agree.  Voters can be somewhat expected to be familiar with the aims and platform of the larger party, because that is what the press covers.  But it would be unrealistic to expect the average voter to have to examine the exact positions of their local representative - there is really nowhere convenient to get that information.  Attending the candidate's rallies or reading their own communications does not have much in terms of adversarial fact checking like press coverage.

Comment: `-n!` I always thought that the way democracy works is that there is reasonable assumption made by voters that their elected representatives will vote in a way that *represents* the voters who put them there, or at a bare minimum, in a way that is to their benefit. Isn't that the general idea behind a [representative democracy](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/lesson-plans/Government_and_You_handouts.pdf)? When did "party above constituency" become a reasonable assumption?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica ditto

Comment: Related: [Are voters in the US generally aware of how and when their congressional representatives are being whipped?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/66156/16047)

Comment: @uhoh  You misunderstand.  In order to represent the constituency they *must* vote according to party and not personal whim.  The Constituency says "We want a Conservative" and they expect to get a Conservative.  If that Conservative decides to vote with Labour, then they are **not** representing the Constituency that elected them.  The idea that a constituency could choose a Conservative and get someone who votes with Labour would be profoundly undemocratic.

Comment: You've misconstrued my comment: "vote according to party and not personal whim" is not at all what I said. How could "a way that represents the voters who put them there, or at a bare minimum, in a way that is to their benefit." be considered "personal whim"? Party above constituency is *fundamentally undemocratic* and opens the door to all kinds of nasty stuff.

Comment: If you say "I am the Conservative candidate" and are elected on that basis, how are you voting "in a way that represents the voters who put you there" if you don't vote as a Conservative?

Comment: I don't see relevance; if someone says "I am the Conservative candidate... and so ***I will vote as I am told by the party*** rather than represent my constituents or their interests" they (hopefully) may not get elected in a democracy. Voting the way the party tells you to is how it's done in single-party systems (e.g. China, Russia). How can a party not evolve and adapt if not through individual experimentation of its members?

Comment: No  it should be "so I will vote as I am told by the party rather and by doing so I represent my constituents or their interests".  as the alternative is "I will vote with a party that my constituents have expressly rejected"

Comment: It's in the interests of voters to have a government that is capable of making decisions. Whips fulfil this aim, by encouraging representatives to vote as a bloc. Members can still vote against the party if they like, but they can't expect to receive benefits from the party if they vote against it. Experience has shown party democracy is the most effective way of organising a democracy (e.g. the US started out with founding fathers who didn't believe in parties, but soon changed its mind.)

Comment: "There is a reasonable assumption ..." This part of the answer is too simplistic. Policies have an uncountable number of nuances. There might be many reasons why two people belonging to the same party might disagree on a vote. That is why there is the say: **The level of democracy of a country is proportional to the number of representatives**. So the whip is there and has a role, to keep the voters aware of what the MPs they elected are doing, but let's avoid calling it reasonable expectations.